# Sci-fi serial movie: Hyper-evolved human "queen" captured by scientists

Tags: story-identification, tv, evolution

Gosh, I dont know where to start... I watched some serial movie from some sci-fi television (I don't remember which one) the moment that I captured was when the humans captured the queen of the evolved humans (the happening event was in the near future and the base of this group of people was surrounded by the evolved humans that was looking like savages)

In the end of the episode that I watched was a scene where the remaining humans (they looked like scientists) were arguing about keeping the queen inside or not, some of them were thinking that she let herself be captured so she can learn about her enemy from inside the lab, she looked hairless and brown and very smart. When the arguing ended, the queen killed one of the females with something sharp. There were some familiar actors and actresses that I no longer remember (I really tried to but failed to remember). I'm 100% sure that the chick that died was in some big movie but I'm not sure which one, and I can't remember her face either. I'm not sure which program I watched this serial movie episode on. It looked kind of new and catchy.

Comment: This needs a lot of fixing.  First off, _when_ did you see this.  What would you estimate as the age of the film? Also, it would worth breaking the main points apart so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you watched an episode of Wayward Pines

I cant find the exact scene you describe but see if this looks familiar;

Comment: You insert video just by including the link.

Comment: That popped into my mind, but I only ever really read the books, where they were pale. Cool!